# Seizing multiple resources sets by Java

Tags: anylogic

I have a generic process which will vary in terms of the type of carriers involved for different processes. E.g. Process A uses Carrier 1, Process B uses Carrier 2 and 3 and so on. Hence I have a col_Carrier to store the types of Carriers involved with each of the processes. However, as the number of Carriers can vary, I need a way for the model to dynamically read all the contents within col_Carrier instead of hardcoding it to col_Carrier.get(index).

I tried various methods but I can't figure out what is the correct Java code to allow me to read all the items within the col_Carrier for this scenario. Ive tried:

```
{{ 
    col_Carrier
}}
```

this gives an error Type mismatch: cannot convert ArrayList to ResourcePool

```
{{ 
    (ResourcePool) I : col_Carrier
}}
```

this gives 2 errors: The field Agent.i is not visible, Syntax error on token ":", :: expected

[image]

Comment: in your resource sets use a function getResources that returns a ResourcePool[][]    i might answer more in detail later

Comment: Hi Felipe, greatly appreciate it. Would love to have some guidance on how to write the function as well :)